# Joining Two Unrelated Tables to Find Record(s)

Tags: mysql

I am working on creating a query that looks to see renewed records from a previous record that still currently has an outstanding balance.

Now I have manage to make a query that has the child record look back at the parent record. Basically what this first query will do is go through and look at the records, that have been renewed, and then compare it to the previous parent records expiration date.

```
Select BL1.RECORDID as RECIID, BL2.EXPIRATIONDATE as ParentRecordExpirationDate, 
        (DATEDIFF(DD,GETDATE(),BL2.ExpirationDate)*-1)as DAYSOVER 
from BLLICENSE BL1 
JOIN RECORD BL2 on BL1.RECORDPARENTID = BL2.RECORDID 
Where CONVERT(date,BL2.EXPIRATIONDATE) < GETDATE() 
    AND BL1.RECORDSTATUSID IN('Renewed',
        'Issued', 'In Review',
        'On Hold', 'Submitted', 
        'Fees Due')
```

Now that I have that first checkbox taken care of I am trying to figure out how I can get the query to incorporate the below query so that I can do the renewal check and also check to see if their is an open invoice/balance due.

```
Select DISTINCT(BLL.RECORDID) 
from CAINVOICE CAI 
JOIN CAINVOICEFEE CAIF on CAIF.CAINVOICEID = CAI.CAINVOICEID
JOIN CACOMPUTEDFEE CACF on CACF.CACOMPUTEDFEEID = CAIF.CACOMPUTEDFEEID
JOIN RECORD BLLF on BLLF.CACOMPUTEDFEEID = CACF.CACOMPUTEDFEEID
JOIN RECORD BLL on BLL.RECORDID = BLLF.RECORDID
    AND CAI.CASTATUSID in (1,2,3,6,7,8))
```

I tried to use a Union of the two but sadly that did not work as "All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists."

I was going to try and join the tables but using that Distinct option on query #2 I feel like causes that idea to fail.

Comment: FYI, `DISTINCT` is not a function that applies to a specific column. It's a keyword that applies to the entire `SELECT` list.

Comment: The question isn't very clear, but I think you can put the second query in a subquery or CTE, and then use `LEFT JOIN` to join with it. If it returns a non-null value then there's an open invoice.

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved it. I should have just taken the easy route and used query designer.

> SELECT distinct BLLICENSE.BLLICENSEID
> FROM BLLICENSE INNER JOIN
> BLLICENSEFEE ON BLLICENSE.BLLICENSEID = BLLICENSEFEE.BLLICENSEID INNER JOIN
> CACOMPUTEDFEE ON BLLICENSEFEE.CACOMPUTEDFEEID = CACOMPUTEDFEE.CACOMPUTEDFEEID INNER JOIN
> CAINVOICEFEE ON CACOMPUTEDFEE.CACOMPUTEDFEEID = CAINVOICEFEE.CACOMPUTEDFEEID INNER JOIN
> CAINVOICE ON CAINVOICEFEE.CAINVOICEID = CAINVOICE.CAINVOICEID
> WHERE CAINVOICE.CASTATUSID IN ('Due', 'Past Due', 'Overdue') and BLLICENSE.BLLICENSEPARENTID IS NOT NULL AND (CONVERT(date, BLLICENSE.ISSUEDDATE) <= CONVERT(date, GETDATE()))

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).